# Running an external shell command after org export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, hooks

I'm writing a paper using org-mode, using the LaTeX export function to generate the `.tex` file I need to submit to the journal.

How can I run an external shell command every time I to the `C-c C-e l l` for LaTeX export?  I need to apply a patch to the generated `.tex` file.

Answer (score 1):

You might do this by using Org's [publishing](http://orgmode.org/manual/Publishing.html#Publishing) functions, and setting up one for your project. Take a look in particular at the setting [`publishing-function`](http://orgmode.org/manual/Publishing-action.html#Publishing-action), which allows you to specify an arbitrary elisp function by which an org file within a given project is exported.

The publishing function might do a standard export to latex then run a shell command on the resulting file like this:

```
(defun publish-latex-and-patch (plist filename pub-dir)
  "Export a latex file then patch it by reversing lines"
  (let ((outfile
         (org-publish-org-to 'latex filename ".tex" plist pub-dir)))
    (shell-command (format "tac %s > %s-patched.tex"
                           outfile
                           (file-name-sans-extension outfile)))))
```

And you would then export your file by doing `C-c C-e P f` ("publish this file"). Obviously replace `tac` with your patching command, and exercise hygiene (e.g. escaping) if passing untrusted input to the shell.

There are also many org-export hooks, but they are more designed to modify specify elements within the parse tree during the export process.